# Error in "with_transaction_returning_status" during save

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

During the save! of an object, I get a weird "ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" error. Debugging leads to the method with_transaction_returning_status in file Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/transactions.rb,
where self.class.transaction turns out to be nil, which seems strange. Stepping over the self.class.transaction line causes the error to be raised. Any ideas why this could go wrong?

```
def with_transaction_returning_status
  status = nil
  self.class.transaction do
    add_to_transaction
    status = yield
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless status
  end
  status
end
```

Comment: there are so many possible causes... it would be a good thing to post some context (the code you execute) and the error message (full stacktrace including line-numbers).

Comment: @phoet: no need to look for a solution anymore. What seemed to be a good idea to get a ',' as delimiter in an input field, by overriding the to_s method for BigDecimal turned out into a nightmare, leading to the above... Removed the to_s override, and problem was gone...

Comment: you should answer your own question so that others don't have to look at it any longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-issue: what seemed to be a good idea to get a ',' as delimiter in an input field, by overriding the to_s method for BigDecimal turned out into a nightmare, leading to the above... Removed the to_s override, and problem was gone...